# How to run UIDAI Aadhar sample application on OSX/Linux

Tags: java, java-7

I'm trying to run the sample application from UIDAI developer portal to test Aadhar API, but the instructions are for windows based os.

How can I run the sample app under Mac OSX or Linux?

Below is the run.bat file that is suppose to run the project on windows os

```
echo off

echo Enter OS Type (1: 32-bit, 2: 64 Bit):
set /p OSBITS=

IF %OSBITS%==1 set OSTYPE=win32
IF %OSBITS%==2 set OSTYPE=x64

echo %OSTYPE%

set PATH=%PATH%;dll\%OSTYPE%

set KEYFILE=pub

set PROP_DEC_PASS=UID12345

echo Starting Authentication Client using %OSTYPE% DLLs

java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp .;jar/*  -Xms512m -Xmx756m ``in.gov.uidai.auth.sampleapp.SampleClientMainFrame
```

PFA link to developer portal https://www.developer.uidai.gov.in/node/22

Comment: perhaps it is more better to ask the App provider out for some help.As they first need to support it.

Comment: @SasiKathimanda It's a govt provided API, all docs are windows related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out I had to modify the windows specific bash syntax to *nix

below code worked for me

```
export KEYFILE=pub

export PROP_DEC_PASS=UID12345

echo Starting Authentication Client

java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp .:jar/*  -Xms512m -Xmx756m in.gov.uidai.auth.sampleapp.SampleClientMainFrame
```